# Sql statment working fine locally but not on server

Tags: java, postgresql, dropwizard, heroku-postgres

I am trying to insert some data in postgresql.

```
PreparedStatement preparedStatement= connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO userr (joining_date, country_code, mobile_no, email_id) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?) RETURNING id");
        preparedStatement.setDate(1,  currentDate);
        preparedStatement.setInt(2, countryCode);
        preparedStatement.setString(3, mobileNo);
        preparedStatement.setString(4, emailId);
        ResultSet x= preparedStatement.executeQuery();
```

when I try this on my local machine every thing works fine. But as I shift it to my server it throws an error

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException:Error: null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
```

My table create statement looks like this.

```
private static void createTableUser(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
    Statement statement= connection.createStatement();
    statement.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE USERR"
            +"("+
            "id SERIAL,"+
            "first_name VARCHAR(20),"+
            "middle_name VARCHAR(20),"+
            "last_name VARCHAR(20),"+
            "age INTEGER,"+
            "image_url VARCHAR(250),"+
            "joining_date DATE ,"+
            "country_code INTEGER,"+
            "mobile_no VARCHAR(20),"+
            "email_id VARCHAR(20),"+
            "CONSTRAINT pk_user PRIMARY KEY (id)"+
            ")"
    );
    statement.close();
}
```

I dont know why this happened even though it was working well locally.

N.B: schema of userr contain 'id' as primary key and many other were there.

Comment: yes data I provide is correct

Comment: Delete table? Huh? Is that an alias for drop table?

Comment: It's pretty hard to ignore. You write some garbage code in the question, who knows what's the real code you're running.

Comment: yeah.. i edited that one

Answer (score 0):

The ID column doesn't have a default value linked to a sequence and you are not providing this value either.

Comment: I updated the question and added table to it. pls check.

Comment: That's your create statement, not the table definition that you should read on the server. Obviously the tables are not the same locally and on your server

Comment: yes that is what I am asking when I run this on local postgres it is working then why not on server

Comment: how its different??

Comment: The difference is written in my answer. Look at the table definition on your server

Comment: if you can edit my mistake and post back then please do this favor

Comment: Look at the table definition on your server, as it is not corresponding to the create statement you have posted.

Comment: i cant see. .I dont have the access that much

Comment: I saw many articles meanwhile and everywhere same statement is written but this statement 'serial' has some expanded form but if we write serial that  is enough to state auto increment.

Comment: @ShubhamBhewanewala You can see the column default value using `SELECT column_name, column_default FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE LOWER(table_name) = 'userr';`